# Access nested dict key within the same dict

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary, optimization, constructor

Basically, I have around 10 function calls that do some stuff on external API when a user is on-boarded to my portal. right now I have the function calls like this.

```
> function1(arg1, arg2) 
> return_val = function2(arg3) 
...
> function10(arg5, return_val)
```

Can I do something like this, where I define my 9-10 functions one by one, and then loop over and call them and store each functions returned value in a key. and is It safe that I am accessing a nested dict within my dict?
This code works but I want to know if this is viable and how safe/bad is it?

```
import math
def add(a,b):
    return a+b

test = {
    1: {
        "function": add,
        "args": [50, 50],
        "returns": None
        },
    2: {
        "function": math.pow,
        "args": [test[1]['returns'], 3],
        "returns": None
        }
}
for index, action in test.items():
    action['returns'] = action['function'](*action['args'])

print(test[2]['returns'])

# This print 100^3 -> 1000000.00
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong doing this way.

Comment: @bigbounty Alright thank you. This solves my purpose as I have some logic and logs post every function call so I can just keep it in the loop and it prevents me form repeating in 10 times.